# Preserving attributes of linejoin through concatenation

Tags: postgresql, fme-form, manifold

I've run into a bit of a problem, I'm working on a layer of connected lines which represent geological faults and contacts. These lines were broken into many small segments so to get rid unnecessary line segments and thus reduce the size of the layer. I joined the lines in FME and I joined based on certain attributes that I wanted to preserve (I couldn't preserve them all or the linejoin would not reduce the number of lines enough).

However, now I want to bring back some of the lesser important attributes such as the name's of the geologist who mapped the lines. Each line had a source author name telling me the geologist's name. Now that I've line joined I want to find a way to place these authors name's back into the geolines and have the new single lines that were previously composed of two or more segments to have all the author names. So I want to end up with a concatenated column with the source authors names for each line listed.

For example,

If I had two connected line segments: 
gid source_author

1 Pete Philips

2 Frank Urt

Now when I combine the two lines I lose this information. So I just have:

gid source_author

1   <-blank->

But what I want is to fill this new line with the previous source authors concatenated together

gid source_author

1   Pete Philips Frank Urt

My brain hurts thinking about it and I haven't really been able to come up with a solution or tried anything that even remotely worked. If anyone has any ideas how I could do this that would be great!

Thanks for the help!

PS. I'm working in Manifold, FME and pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly here is what you could do:

1. In the LineJoiner transformer there is a parameter where you can specify a List Name. If you do this then you will end up with list attributes that look like this:
   MyList.gid source_author{}.  So on a line that was joined where there was more than one author on the two segment you might have:
   MyList.gid source_author{0}= Pete Philips and also MyList.gid source_author{0}= Frank Urt
2. Then use the ListConcatenator which will combine all of the element in the list with a delimiter - in your case it looks like you want a space (although maybe a comma would be better with names)
   Hope this helps

Comment: Is the LineJoiner in FME or Postgresql?